# Unable to move between ViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c

My app downloads data, and when the data has downloaded I'm trying to send the user back to the app's main ViewController, but it's not working.

Code:

```
   UIStoryboard *storyboard=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    Full_Sync *fullSyncController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ViewControllerROOTIdentifier"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:fullSyncController animated:NO];
```

The method is being called as the NSlog works, but this code doesn't seem to run. The code works perfectly in other parts of the app. Not sure why it won't work from here.

Comment: Is `self.navigationController` nil? Where is called that code? Do you have extra logs?

Comment: What is Full_Sync?

Comment: Check `self` or `Current ViewController` is under `Navgation Controller` or not.
`Push`, `Pop` can only be done if there is `Navigation stack`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to go back on the main thread after receiving a result from the API. Network calls are asynchronous tasks made on another thread, and since you need to make any UI-related action on the main thread, you need to do this (Objective-C) :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   // Perform your transition here.
});
```

You also need to make sure that the view controller that is performing the transition in embed in a UINavigationController !